# Configure ESLint in WebStorm by some settings file

Tags: eslint, webstorm

First, I wish to configure the ESLint plugin to look for a specific location to find the ESLint configuration file (so basically find `.eslintrc.json` - but I don't want to set it in the project root folder).

I could do it manually:
[image]

I could set `Working directories` to some random folder like the `Documents` one.

But I look for kind of automatic way, meaning, that if someone want the same configuration, he could clone my project and have it out of the box.

The equivalent scenario in VSCode is creating `.vscode/settings.json` file and then I could share this file. I do know I somehow(?) can use the `.idea` folder and configure a configuration file within this folder but I could find out how to do so.

I tried to export my project configuration:

[image]

But I couldn't see in the exported `zip` file any settings related with ESLint. I just used this export tool to maybe understand how to do so alone without the export tool.

Comment: *"But I couldn't see in the exported zip file any settings related with ESLint."* Your first screenshot (the icon at the end of the settings breadcrumbs) shows that it's a project-specific settings. Such settings are stored in `.idea` (or perhaps in a local part of the workspace config) and not in the IDE-wide config that you can export.

Comment: I don't have any `.idea` folder. I don't understand where can I find these configurations?

Comment: When you create a project in WebStorm, it will create `.idea` subfolder there: e.g. the project is located in `/Projects/MyProject` then it will be `/Projects/MyProject/.idea`. Do not forget -- the folder starts with a dot, so it's a "hidden" folder.

Comment: @LazyOne

Thank you I found it